# this.props and prevProps are equal

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Inside componentDidUpdate, alert is not triggered when props change.

You can run this code in codePen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMmqKe?editors=1011)

```
const state = observable({
  isOpen: false
})

state.close = function () {
  state.isOpen = false
}

state.open = function () {
  state.isOpen = true
}

const Home = observer(class home extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.store.isOpen !== prevProps.store.isOpen) {
      // this line is not executed
      alert('reset');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.props.store.isOpen
      ? <button onClick={this.props.store.close}>close</button>
      : <button onClick={this.props.store.open}>open</button>
    );
  }
})

render(<Home store={state} />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

`this.props.store` and `prevProps.store` will always refer to the same `store` object, so `isOpen` will always be the same on both sides of the equals operator.

You could instead use the [`componentWillReact` life cycle hook](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#componentwillreact-lifecycle-hook) to run some code when the component will update because of a change in an observable.

```
const Home = observer(class home extends Component {
  componentWillReact() {
    alert('reset');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.props.store.isOpen
      ? <button onClick={this.props.store.close}>close</button>
      : <button onClick={this.props.store.open}>open</button>
    );
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the if statement in you componentDidUpdate():

```
!this.props.store.isOpen ? alert("reset"): null;
```